# Getting Result From Barcode Scan

Tags: android, xamarin.android, zxing

I am able to invoke the barcode scanner via intents, but when I try to capture the values returned by the scan based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604550/calling-barcode-scanner-on-a-button-click-in-android-application), I get the following errors when trying to build the solution.

- Android.Content.Intent' does not contain a definition for 'getStringExtras' and no extension method 'getStringExtras' accepting a first argument of type 'Android.Content.Intent' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- The name 'RESULT_CANCELED' does not exist in the current context
- The name 'RESULT_OK' does not exist in the current context

Here is my code for both invoking the scanner and trying to return results.
Click event is in onCreate.  onActivityResult is a method in the same.cs, same class, same namespace as the scan.Click event.

```
    Button scan = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.scan);
        scan.Click += (o, e) =>
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.SetPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
            intent.PutExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        };

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if (requestCode == 0)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This approach is probably not the best way to implement this, as your app will crash if zxing's barcode scanner is not installed.

Comment: (He just has to catch ActivityNotFoundException or check for the package first, or use IntentIntegrator -- easy to not trip on that.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that your `onActivityResult` method has not been properly translated from Java to Mono for Android.

It should look more like:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            String contents = data.GetStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = data.GetStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
        }
        else if (resultCode == Result.Canceled)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The highlights of the translation are:

1. Correct signature (and override) for [OnActivityResult](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=M:Android.App.Activity.OnActivityResult)
2. Use the [Result](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T:Android.App.Result) enumeration
3. The getStringExtra method in Java is [GetStringExtra](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=M:Android.Content.Intent.GetStringExtra%28System.String%29) in C#

Answer (score 1):

Try using the utility class provided by zxing, which can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java). This will also prevent your application from crashing if the Barcode Scanner app is not installed.

Comment: I would love to implement this way, but the link is just a whole lot of java which as you can tell is not my wheelhouse.  If there is a monodroid example of just opening the scanner and getting the results using IntentIntegrator, it would be much appreciated.  I haven't been able to find one on google.