# Get callBack from Goggles

Tags: android, android-intent, ocr, zxing, google-goggles

I know that there are not  an API for google toggle. But it listen to com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN
So with

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
startActivity(intent);
```

i can open goggles app.
My question is, 
it is possible to get callback in my app?
i want to process on the text result.
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Start the Scan activity using `startActivityForResult`
Then implement the `onActivityResult` method to receive the result.

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5604598/630668
and http://campevans.net/getting-zxing-into-an-existing-android-applic

Comment: thx, but i always get a RESULT_CANCELED resultCode, and a null intent. Do you know why?

Comment: Probably You are getting RESULT_CANCELD due to the scanning is not working.